# jasmine test continuing to act althought WaitsFor is true

Tags: backbone.js, jasmine

I'm working with backbone and jasmine and now 
trying to test the callCount of 'sync' method, when model saved.
For some strange reason the sync handler continue to handle the sync even after the done variable is true (this is there i planned to stop the test)
I'm a newbie for jasmine so i guess i didn't understand something elementar here...

here is my speck:

```
describe('Model :: User', function() {

  var mockData = { name: 'Foo Bar' };

  beforeEach(function() {
    var that = this,
        done = false;

    require(['app/namespace','app/models/UserModel','app/collections/UsersCollection'], function(namespace, UserModel ,UsersCollection) {
        that.users = new UsersCollection();
        that.user = new UserModel();
         done = true;
    });

    waitsFor(function() {
      return done;
    }, "Create Models");




  });

  afterEach(function(){
    var done = false,
        isDone = function(){ return done; };

    this.users.fetch({
      success: function(c) {
        console.log('after the test calling destory of collection...')
        c.each(function(m){
          m.destroy();
        });
        done = true;
      }
    });

    waitsFor(isDone);

    done = false;
    this.user.destroy({
      success: function(){
        console.log('after the test calling destory of model...')
        done = true;
      }
    });

    waitsFor(isDone);

  });

  describe('.save()', function() {
    it('should call sync when saving', function() {
      var done = false,
          spy = jasmine.createSpy();
      this.user.on('sync', spy);
      this.user.on('sync', function(){

        console.log('checking spy.callCount-'+spy.callCount);
    //------------------------------------------------
        if(!done)//why i need this if ?!
            expect(spy.callCount).toEqual(1);
        done = true;

      }, this);

      this.user.save(mockData);


      waitsFor(function() { return done; });

    });

  });


});
```

The test workiing correctly only if i add "if(!done)" condition before expect statement,
otherwise it continue to count sync calls that caused by destroy after the test...
Thanks forwards

Answer (score 1, accepted):

There are some of issues with this test. First of all, you dont need to test that the `sync` event is fired when saving your model cause this is provided by another framework, which is hopefully tested.

Second you should use the [fake server](http://sinonjs.org/docs/#server) of [SinonJs](http://sinonjs.org/) to not mess with async calls. With sinon your request will be called immediately, which means you dont need `waitsFor`. Also assertions in callback seems a bit odd.

```
this.server = sinon.fakeServer.create();
server.respondWith({data: 'someData'})
server.autoRespond = true; //so when the request start the fake server will immediately call the success callback
var spy = jasmine.createSpy();
this.user.on('sync', spy);
this.user.save(mockData);
expect(spy.callCount).toEqual(1);
```

Comment: Thank you for answering. I'm new to backbone and jasmine and i simply trying to copy all the tests from https://github.com/uzikilon/Todos/tree/master/test/jasmine , my code is almost the same, but for some reason the test running differently. For faking the server i'm using backbone.localStorage